# Cannot catch exception in Controller in Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception

In my Spring Boot app, I implemented a global exception handler class as shown below:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid() {
        // code omitted for brevity 

        return ResponseEntity.unprocessableEntity().body(errorResponse);
    }
    
    // other type of exceptions
}
```

And in my Controller, I return `ResponseEntity<ApiResponse>` as shown below:

```
@GetMapping("/categories/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<CategoryResponse>> findById(@PathVariable long id){
    final CategoryResponse response = categoryService.findById(id);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(
        new ApiResponse<>(
            Instant.now(clock).toEpochMilli(), Constants.SUCCESS, response));
}
```

Here is my `ApiResponse` class:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ApiResponse<T> {

    private Long timestamp;
    private final String message;
    private final T data;

    public ApiResponse(Long timestamp, String message) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.message = message;
        this.data = null;
    }
}
```

My problem is that; when there is an error, I cannot catch it on Controller and `GlobalExceptionHandler` directly return error in `ResponseEntity<Object>` type. When I send requests via Postman, I get the error message, but when I implemented a frontend app, I realized that this format is different than return type when there is no error.

So, I think I should manage the exception as well in the Controller and return the same type data to frontend so that the return value can easily be manipulated. How should I solve this problem? I do not want to use try-catch and do not move my business logic to the Controller. Instead, maybe I should change return type of `ResponseEntity<Object>` in the exception handler to a similar one in the Controller. Or may need to return exception to the Controller. What should I do?

**Update:** I had already implemented a custom exception class:

```
public class ElementAlreadyExistsException extends RuntimeException {

    public ElementAlreadyExistsException() {
        super();
    }

    public ElementAlreadyExistsException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public ElementAlreadyExistsException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

And use it in my `GlobalExceptionHandler` as shown below:

```
@ExceptionHandler(ElementAlreadyExistsException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleElementAlreadyExistsException(ElementAlreadyExistsException ex, WebRequest request) {
    return buildErrorResponse(ex, HttpStatus.CONFLICT, request);
}
```

And the errors are build as shown below:

```
private ResponseEntity<Object> buildErrorResponse(Exception ex,
                                                      HttpStatus httpStatus,
                                                      WebRequest request) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(httpStatus.value(), message);
        return ResponseEntity.status(httpStatus).body(errorResponse);
    }
```

And here is the response class that I use for exception:

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ErrorResponse {

    private final int status;
    private final String message;
    private String stackTrace;
    private List<ValidationError> errors;

    @Data
    private static class ValidationError {
        private final String field;
        private final String message;
    }

    public void addValidationError(String field, String message) {
        if (Objects.isNull(errors)) {
            errors = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        errors.add(new ValidationError(field, message));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create a custom exception class that extends RuntimeException and define the error message and status code. Then in your GlobalExceptionHandler, you can catch this custom exception and return a ResponseEntity of type ApiResponse with the error message and status code. This way, your error handling logic remains in the GlobalExceptionHandler and your controller returns a consistent response format.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helps. I added my update to clarify you a little bit more. So, under these conditions, should I merge my `ApiResponse` and `ErrorResponse` classes and return the same type like `ResponseEntity<MergedApiResponse<T>>`  using `MergedApiResponse` ?

Comment: @AshishSrivastava Chico? Are you there?